# Col in Bootstrap navbar, but want full width toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, navbar

I use a navbar-fixed-bottom to display two main buttons/actions, centered. Col-3 for each of them so I still have two col-3 I can use.

 
I wanted to make a sort of sliding up "About us" section, and use the collapse property of navbar to achieve this.

Here is the bootply : http://www.bootply.com/bAw2Wj2gGZ

My issue is that since the "About us" depends on a col-3, I can't have the content and its inside links to span full width. Its max-width remains col-3.

I tried table, table cell, and many other things, nothing works well.

Is it doable ? Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can make it using jQuery to get the width and to set it for the list wrapper

Comment: Thanks @dyaa I feared I'd have to resort to something like that. I wanted to first see if it wasn't possible with standard elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into implementing Animate.css. It's a better option than relying on javascript that native CSS can handle.

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

You can just add the animate class and the class effect. The slideInUp should work for your needs. It's much faster and less buggier than JS.

Comment: Thank you @Miura-shi seems indeed like a an efficient solution for what I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: @Volumineux No problem! If this answer helped you please accept, check the answer. This will help others know too. Thanks!

Comment: Done ! and thank you again. (sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow)

Comment: @Volumineux No problem and welcome! All the best on your web development journey :)